# Show once popup

Tags: php, javascript

Say I wanted to create a popup for my website that only showed once (if the user either filled it out or clicked the "do not display again" button), how would I do so. I am creating the popup and form using javascript and html, passing it in php to a database.

Comment: save if it is clicked in a cookie maybe? Or If the user is logged in in a session variable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a cookie which would be downloaded to the client's computer. When your webpage loaded, it would need to check for this cookie, and if not found, or a flag inside it had a property "noPopup=true" for instance, not display the popup.

Comment: ok I have never done this before - is there an easy tutorial you know?

Comment: Hi Ben, Sorry, I don't really use PHP, but this page looks like it has the information you need http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php